# R Mac binary package builder for X86-64

Tags: r, macos, x86, x86-64

The excellent resource https://mac.r-project.org/macbuilder/submit.html makes it easy to build binary Mac packages for ARM64 to distribute to others.  I have been unable to find a similar resource for X86-64 Macs.   Does anyone know of such a service?  I run Linux myself so can't build a Mac binary on my own.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is what you could be looking for, but you could use a CI/CD system like GitHub actions, Appveyor, Azure Pipelines, TeamCity, etc. They should be able to build your package for any system. Pricing varies, and open-source packages may be free.

Comment: That is very helpful to know.  I'm looking for one that is Mac X86-64 ready.

Comment: Most if not all of them should have environments for Windows, MacOS, and Linux. You can choose different architectures (Intel/AMD vs ARM). It’s similar to some of the options by Llex, but with the ability to build automatically if you push changes to GitHub for example.